# Can I convert FBX files to Three.js in runtime?

Tags: three.js, webgl, fbx

I would like to build an .fbx viewer in HTML5, which would load *.fbx files (3D models)
and will convert them on-the-fly to json and present them, using Three.js(+WebGL).

Is this possible? I only see Python scripts online that does it.

Comment: Maybe the question is not very clear but three.js and WebGL are only for display of your data. You still have to get your data to Three.js through (possibly) json. So why don't you like python to do the reading of the format for you?

Comment: I will run this in a very specific environment and I can't (or prefer not to) use Python.
I know AutoDesk has a C++ SDK too. Any C++ solution for that?

Comment: it is easier to integrate python with the web than it is to integrate c++ with the web. So python is your best bet. Which python library converts fbx to json?

Comment: This script here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/fbx/convert_to_threejs.py

Comment: This version is a slightly more up to date version: https://github.com/zfedoran/convert-to-threejs-json

Also, porting the script to C++ would not be very hard as the API is nearly the same (source: I wrote that python file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can at present only do a [non-online conversion](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/converters/fbx) of FBX to three.js formats, rather than loading / importing FBX directly into a live scene.

Comment: the link is broken